# disable and enable click events with a counter and transition effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following lines of code in my web page - [demo/example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vORgBv).

**HTML:**

```
<button class="wrong-answer" onclick="showResult(this)">42</button>
<button class="right-answer" onclick="showResult(this)">43</button>

<p id="answer" class="answer-display-hidden">answer</p>

<div class="incorrect">
    <span>Incorrect:</span>
    <p>0</p>
</div>

<div class="correct">
    <span>Correct:</span>
    <p>0</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.answer-display-visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}

.answer-display-hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 1s, opacity 1s linear;
}

.incorrect, .correct {float: left; padding-right: 20px}
```

**JS:**

```
var incorrectCalls = 0;
var correctCalls = 0;

function showResult(b) {
  var res = document.getElementById('answer');

  if (b.classList.contains('right-answer')) {
    res.innerHTML = '<span class="right">right</span>';

    correctCalls++;
        var cor = $('.correct > p:first');
        cor[0].innerHTML = correctCalls;
  } 

  else {
    res.innerHTML = '<span class="wrong">wrong</span>';

    incorrectCalls++;
    var incor = $('.incorrect > p:first');
    incor[0].innerHTML = incorrectCalls;
  }

  res.classList.remove("answer-display-hidden");
  res.classList.add("answer-display-visible");

  setTimeout(function() {
        res.classList.add("answer-display-hidden");
  }, 2000);
}
```

How can I de-activate the `right-answer` counter during the fade-in and wait effect on the text, and then re-activate afterwards?  This is so that the user can't manipulate the counter (click on the button quickly before the text is displayed).

Comment: Have you tried adding the attribute `disabled` to the button in those few seconds it takes for the answer to appear and disappear. My knowledge of JS is too small to know where to add it, but you might be able to figure it out. I think you have to use `setAttribute("disabled");` and `removeAttribute("disabled");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setTimeout function when button clicked.

[Live Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPMKpz)

Code Block:

```
function showResult(b) {
 .
 .
 .
  $(".right-answer").prop("disabled", true);
  $(".wrong-answer").prop("disabled", true);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".right-answer").prop("disabled", false);
    $(".wrong-answer").prop("disabled", false);
  }, 2600);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution

[WORKING DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kypeat6x/9/)

Removed CSS code and following is the jQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".wrong-answer").click(function(){
        $(".right-answer").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#answer").text("WRONG").fadeIn(5000,function(){

            $(this).fadeOut(5000,function(){
                $(".right-answer").removeAttr("disabled");
            });
        })

    });

});
```

Comment: Could you please include the counters in your solution?

Comment: Updated the code with this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kypeat6x/10/. You can do same with right-answer button click also.

Comment: If I select the button as quickly as I can, the counter counts each click on the button.  However, I'm looking for a solution where the counter won't count during the transition effect with regards to the text.  For example, if you select the button really fast, the counter will count the first click, then stop and only begin again after the text has faded out.